# Limit KiCAD track selection to current layer

Tags: pcb, kicad, tools

When I do the track selection in KiCAD and click `Select -> Connected Tracks` it also selects tracks connected through vias on the back of the board.

I only want to select tracks on the current layer. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Please note the question is not asking about selection in general, but rather about a very specific mechanism for selecting **connected tracks**.  The goal is to get that to capture only the pieces on the current layer.  That said, the goal is perhaps ambiguous - if a route goes through a via to another layer then comes back to the original layer elsewhere on the board, should the other piece be selected too?

Comment: Could you explain your usecase? Maybe there is a different route to get the same result without needing this feature.

Comment: I don't know of a better method than deleting the via before selecting all connected tracks ("U" shortcut), most of the time it is just fine (the via needed to move anyway) but sometimes it can be annoying as you'll need to re-place the via afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

Try enabling enabling high contrast mode (View -> Contrast mode -> High contrast mode or CTRL+H)

Comment: While this might be useful for other needs, it's unclear why you think this would help with the problem of the question, and in fact testing confirms **it does not solve the problem**.  Perhaps re-read the question and consider exactly what is being asked?

Comment: I thought the purpose of this would be *highlighting* the net, since performing any edits on net, that spans multiple layers seems to be of very limited (if any) use